# Shortcut key in PhpStorm to move to HTML end tag

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Having a section of HTML tag:

```
<div>
    /* a long long text */
</div>
```

Suppose the caret is at the begin of the tag `<div>`,
is there any key to move the caret to the closing `</div>`?

There is a similar concept on CSS (doesn't work on HTML) that works fine:

```
.myClass {
    ....
}
```

in this case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>/<kbd>[</kbd> moves to the code block end/start.

[Here is the PhpStorm Default Keymap](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/phpstorm/PhpStorm_ReferenceCard.pdf). I can't find the key I'm looking for.

Comment: Ctrl+] works fine for me in *.html file. What is your IDE version?

Comment: phpStrom 7.1 , I have *.php files .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl + ]</kbd> works just fine in `.html` files. But it fails for HTML tags in `.php`.

It's a known issue -- subscribe to the ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20474

Answer (score 38):

Using PhpStorm 10 && 2016.2:

`Ctrl + shift + m` works just fine!

Comment: What's the name of that shortcut? That may not be the same key combination in Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: This shortcut is called "Move Catet to Matching Brace" and can be found in the settings "Keymap - Editor Actions".

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> works just fine in PHPstorm2016.2!

Comment: I'm on a german keyboard with PhpStorm 2016.3 and Ctrl + m is working for me.

Comment: For me it is CTRL + M too. Any idea if it is possible to delete the opening and closing tag in 1 step?

Answer (score 0):

For me works fine in PhpStorm `2021.1.4` version

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd>    Move Caret to Code block start

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>]</kbd>    Move Caret to Code block end

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>M</kbd>  Move Caret to Maching Brace