# Close last open tag using shortcut key (instead of </)

Tags: phpstorm

Is there way to assign a shortcut key to Auto-close the last open tag?

Right now I have to type `</` for it work.

In NPP, I used to press `Ctrl+.` and it would automatically insert the last open tag without even prompting. Much easier than typing `</` and selecting from a list.

Is there any plugin or feature of phpstorm that can accomplish the same thing?

Thanks!

**P.S.** Also since this is related, is there a way to move the cursor to the matching tag. If my cursor is on `<div id="one">` can the cursor automatically move to the closing tag (or opening tag if my cursor is at the closing tag) using a keyboard shortcut? thanks

Comment: in webstorm, if you just type "div" and hit tab, it will open and close the div, I'm not sure about just closing though.

Comment: @cdbajorin That's Emmet in action.

Comment: *"Much easier than typing </ and selecting from a list."* It closes automatically for me -- no need to choose anything from the list. Possibly that is because you have code completion popup visible at that time.

Comment: I have the same question: In sublime text I can hit CMD+Shift+. and it will automatically close any bracket or DOM tag that isn't already closed. What is the keyboard shortcut for that in phpstorm?

Comment: looks like there isn't one yet.. maybe some plugin can do this?

Comment: For the shortcut key: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25421355/

Comment: @cdbajorin's solution works really well, it should be a standalone answer since it accomplishes the overall goal (saving keystrokes) in a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Complete statement [Shift+Ctrl+Enter]` command.

`<strong>Text` ➔
`[Shift+Ctrl+Enter]` ➔
`<strong>Text</strong>`

Comment: Awesome, while this works as expected, it inserts the tag in the next line (so I have to backspace it to get it on the same line). Does that happen for you too?

Comment: I think this happens based on your HTML formatting settings. For example `strong` is listed as inline element without newlines, while `p` is.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get this working is via a macro, and then assigning a shortcut to it.

1. Type something like: `<div>asdf`
2. Start recording your macro (Edit > Macros > Start Macro Recording, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
3. Type `</` directly after the `asdf`

Your closing div should now have automatically been added:`<div>asdf</div>`

4. Directly stop recording your macro (Edit > Macros > Stop Macro Recording, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
5. You are now asked to enter a macro name, use something like `Insert html end tag`
6. Check if it is working: Type `<div>asdf`, and select Edit > Macros > Playback Last Macro
7. If it is working: assign a shortcut to it in your preference window (Keymap > Macros > `Insert html end tag`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl+}`/`Ctrl+{`to jump to matching closing/opening tag (see what shortcuts are assigned to `Move caret to code block start` and `Move caret to code block end` actions in the keymap you are using).